# How can i set timeout to axios that uses proxy option?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, httprequest

I am using Axios with the proxy option I want to check bad proxy so I decide to set timeout to my GET request.

here is code:

```
let res= await axios.get(`http://somedomain.com`,
        {
            timeout:1500,
            proxy: {
                
                host: proxyList[indexOfProxy].host,
                port: proxyList[indexOfProxy].port,
                auth: {
                    username: '',
                    password: ''
                },
                
            }
        }
    ).catch(err => {
        console.log(`proxy ${indexOfProxy} not working.`);
        
    });
```

but actually timeout did not work, it spends a long time to go to catch block .

Answer (score 0):

Use axios.create()

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://wainot.trade',
    timeout: 5000,
  });

async function run() {
    try {
        let res = await instance.get()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('no')
    }
}
run()
```

Comment: are you using try-catch?